# What is the fastest way to insert rows into a PostgreSQL Database with GeoKettle?

Tags: postgresql, csv, insert, pentaho, kettle

Let's say I have a .csv-File with 100 million rows. I import that csv-file into pentaho Kettle and want to write all rows into a PostgreSQL database. What is the fastest insert-transformation? I have tried the normal table output transformation and the PostgreSQL Bulk Loader (which is way faster than the table output). But still, it is too slow. Is there a faster way than using the PostgreSQL Bulk Loader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the fact that PostgreSQL Bulk Loader runs `COPY table_name FROM STDIN` - there's nothing faster from data load in postgres. Multi-value insert will be slower, just multiple insert will be slowest. So you can't make it faster.

To speed up `COPY` you can:

```
set commit_delay to 100000;
set synchronous_commit to off;
```

and other server side tricks (like dropping indexes before loading).

NB:

[very old but still relevant depesz post](https://www.depesz.com/2007/07/05/how-to-insert-data-to-database-as-fast-as-possible/)

[most probably won't work with pentaho Kettle,but worth of checking pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader)

**update**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html

> synchronous_commit (enum)
>
> Specifies whether transaction commit will wait for WAL records to be
>   written to disk before the command returns a “success” indication to
>   the client. Valid values are on, remote_apply, remote_write, local,
>   and off. The default, and safe, setting is on. When off, there can be
>   a delay between when success is reported to the client and when the
>   transaction is really guaranteed to be safe against a server crash.
>   (The maximum delay is three times wal_writer_delay.) Unlike fsync,
>   setting this parameter to off does not create any risk of database
>   inconsistency: **an operating system or database crash might result in
>   some recent allegedly-committed transactions being lost**, but the
>   database state will be just the same as if those transactions had been
>   aborted cleanly. So, turning synchronous_commit off can be a useful
>   alternative when performance is more important than exact certainty
>   about the durability of a transaction.

(emphasis mine)

Also notice I recommend using `SET`for the session level, so if the GeoKettle does not allow to set config before running commands on postgres, you can use [pgbouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html) `connect_query` for the specific user/database pair, or think some other trick. And if you can't do anything to set `synchronous_commit` per session and you decide to change it per database or user (so it would be applied to GeoKettle connection, don't forget to set it back to `on` after load is over.

Comment: If you're going to recommend changing things like `synchronous_commit`, you should really explain the risks involved...

Comment: @NickBarnes thank you for the comment - updated ticket with warning and some alterntyves